# Basic JQuery/JQueryUI not behaving as expected - where am I going wrong?

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-ui

I'm experimenting for the first time with JQuery/JQUI to create a simple social icon bounce effect.

I thought the code below had nailed it..

http://testing.renewablehull.co.uk/css3.html

..but there are two problems:

- the animations queue (I can't seem to get them to stop with .stop() )
- if you move the mouse around, over and over the icon positioning changes 
  (twitter icon moves below facebook, facebook icon slides left/down).

Obviously I'm missing something here!  I'm a total novice so please be gentle and point me in the right direction.

Many thanks

B.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can prevent the animation from stacking like this:

```
$(document).ready(function ()
{
    $('img').mouseover(function ()
    {
        if (!$(this).hasClass("img-hover"))
        {
            $(this).addClass("img-hover");
            $(this).effect("bounce", { times: 3, distance: 8 }, function ()
            {
                $(this).removeClass("img-hover");
            }, 0);
        }
    });
});
```

Incidentely you can stop your effect using:

```
.stop (true, true);
```

Read the [Jquery documentation on stop](http://api.jquery.com/stop/) to understand why you need `true, true` in there.

Comment: Thanks Jon, this prevented the stacking and subsequently the icons now remain in the correct location.  I'll read up on .stop but with your code I don't need it for this bit to work.

Comment: No, but your question made it seem like you wanted to learn so I added it for depth. =)

Comment: Haha, appreciated, I've got a _lot_ to learn, last coded 19 years ago in Pascal.

Answer (score 0):

Your option is either have it go infinitely as long as they're rolled over it, or only do it once and then stop.  I suggest the latter, as being an end-user.

This is how you make it stop after the first time, its done by using the effect callback:

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
          $('img').hover(function(){
              $(this).effect("bounce", { times:3, distance:8},function(e){

                  //disables it from going again
                  e.preventDefault();

                  //resets the position from relative to static
                  $(this).css('position','static');

              }, 0);                     
          });  
    });
```

Also I've noticed your positioning issue has to do with the jQuery effect leaving the element as `position:relative` so once this changed back to `static`, it looks fine.

Comment: Thanks @Zee - implemented suggestions in: http://testing.renewablehull.co.uk/css5.html - however if I remove the preventDefault (to trigger the effect on each mouse enter) - the moving icon problem remains (even with the css static command) - see: http://testing.renewablehull.co.uk/css6.html .. any ideas?

Comment: In you number 5 example it doesn't trigger on each mouse enter because `e` is not being passed through into that function and therefore throws a javascript error. That's what's stopping it - it never worked in the first place. Keep an eye on javascript errors when developing javascript.